# Broken "Next Editor" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys

For some time now "Next Editor" command in Eclipse changed its behavior: *Before* pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and releasing them instantly switched you to the last editor you visited. *Now* pressing them opens the mini-dialog window with editor to choose, and you *have* to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you changed/upgraded the Eclipse version?

Comment: I don't remember, maybe it upgraded by itself.

Comment: This looks like coming from a version change. You should be able to configure the hotkey used for the last editor to be again Ctrl+F6.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I can set it to Ctrl+F6 (strange behavior remains), but I can't update Eclipse to the latest version.

Comment: @harrymc "Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable" for "Oomph Setup".

Comment: [Eclipse Oomph](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph) is perhaps a dependency that needs to be installed first.

Comment: @harrymc I've completely reinstalled Eclipse, and no updates are available, but the problem is still remains. (Because I don't know how to install dependencies and what is it exactly.)